# Where is the frame.h located in modern Linux implementations? (ubuntu specifically)

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, memory, linker

A book I am reading refers to an include file that **shows how a stack frame looks** on one's UNIX system.

In particular: `/usr/include/sys/frame.h`

I am having trouble finding the modern equivalent. Anyone have an idea? I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Oops--thought I could delete this. I have the same question posted on Super User. If I get an answer there I will link it, since it may be helpful. Sorry for double post!

Comment: You could tell us what system would that be, and what it does/refers to. On my Arch machine, 'locate frame.h' returns nothing of the sort.

Comment: What "stack frame" are you talking about? If I understand correctly, this will depend on the compiler and exact compilation flags, so there won't be any uniform stack frame description. And messing with that isn't sane...

Comment: @vonbrand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_frame#Structure should give a good idea. The exact structure varies between implementations, though, and I want to know what it looks like on my implementation.

Comment: @schaiba what system what would be? And what it refers to? x86 Ubuntu 12.10, and it refers to the stack frame, as my question says. Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good answer was provided on [Super User.](https://superuser.com/questions/562074/where-is-the-frame-h-file-or-its-equivalent-located-on-modern-linux-oses)

Whether or not the files discussed are precise extensions of the legacy file my author refers to remains unknown. However, *one will find most of the relevant knowledge* in the `ptrace.h` file and the `calling.h` file located in the `/.../asm/` directory. This presumes an x86 processor.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK that header file is more an old-school unix or BSD thing, you can find it in *Solaris* and *{Free,Open,Net}BSD*:

- http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/x86/include/frame.h?revision=247047&view=markup
  On FreeBSD it's `/usr/include/machine/frame.h`, there's one for each CPU architecture     if you have the kernel source installed, or rummage around that snvweb link to see the different ones
- there are bits of OpenSolaris in the ZFS for Linux project, you can find the Solaris version here: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/tree/master/lib/libspl/include/sys

See also

- https://blogs.oracle.com/aalok/entry/debugging_on_sparc
- http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html
- http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html

Comment: It certainly is old school: the book is from the mid 90's. The dated nature of the book is well compensated for by technical excellence, though. In fact, there are not so infrequent references to PDP-11's, so you are in the right ballpark with your assumption that it is an old school UNIX file. *That being said, there* **has** *to be some sort of description for what I am seeking--the description of a stack frame.* And that is something I am having difficulty finding.

Comment: You might be curious to see my answer below--someone on Super User suggested two header files that are definitely on the right track. +1'ed you anyways.

Comment: Yes, `ptrace.h` looks good, similar the *BSD `frame.h`, unlike the actual `frame.h`/`frame.i` in the Linux kernel source (whose purpose in unclear to me at this time).